# What is the difference between printing two variables using "+" and "," in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 2
b = 4
print(a, b)
print(str(a) +" " + str(b))
```

Is there a difference between the first print and the second print? If there is, which one should I use?

Comment: You should probably use `print(a, b)` as it is more general. Let Python do the string-casting.  Also,  `print()` accepts a parameter `sep` that defaults to one space, like in your example, but could be modified.

Comment: @SethMMorton. I don't think that's true unless you modify `sep`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The question was edited to remove the difference (by adding in the space manually in the second case). Seth commented before the edit.

Comment: @MartinEG It sounds like you observed these produce the same results and  (correctly) concluded that they do the same thing. Given that the first form requires *significantly* less typing and is much easier to understand at a glance, which do you think you should choose?

Answer (score 2):

`print(a, b)` uses `a` and `b` as function parameters.

`print(str(a) + str(b))` actually concatenates strings and then passes result to `print()` function.

That's the only difference.

But you can get the advantage from `print(a, b)` by using `sep` argument.  This can be helpful when you're passing multiple arguments and you want all of them to be separated with certain text.

Ex:

```py
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
print(a, b, c, sep='--')   # prints 1--2--3
```

Comment: @Aemyl I don't think that's correct. Try this: `a = "hello"; print(a); print(str(a)); print(repr(a))` and report back the differences.

Comment: @Aemyl Another, more definitive way to prove it uses `str` and not `repr` is to create a custom class where `__str__` is defined to return "Banana", and `__repr__` is defined to return "Apple", and then print an instance of the class.

Comment: @SethMMorton you're right, I got confused due to the behaviour of the interactive interpreter